# Corrupted text file with Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider written at top

Tags: windows-10, encryption, android, file-corruption, decryption

I have a file containing some important information which I had marked as hidden on my windows PC. I moved this file to a USB and inserted the USB into my phone. The file had changed its extension to .PFILE and, on changing the extension back to .txt, I found that the file was full of gibberish and random characters. At the top, the words Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0 followed by my Windows username and my computer's name were written. Is there any way to recover the data that was in this file?

Comment: Hopefully you have a backup of the file because it sounds like your actions corrupted the file.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't just mark the file as hidden; you also marked it as encrypted. The [EFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypting_File_System) feature in Windows provides transparent encryption, using a key attached to your Windows account.

Undo your changes – rename the file back to `*.pfile` – and connect the USB drive back to your original computer. If the file is visible, disable the "Encrypt this file" setting in its properties window (under *Advanced…*).

Comment: The encrypt this file setting was unchecked when I plugged the USB into the PC, and the file didn't change back to .txt, it remained a .pfile.